# Website broke in Safari (both Mobile and Mac) (using Flexbox)

Tags: safari, flexbox

so my Website broke. It works fine everywhere except in Safari.
At first I thought it was a mistake during an update - but then I remembered I had an older Version of it (I know this had no displaying issues what so ever) and tested it with Safari (8.0.5 | and mobile)

THE SAME PROBLEM APPEARD.

I have no idea what went wrong.

the page I am talking about. www.platzhirsch.wien

please help

EDIT: This might have appeared after the recent automatic wordpress update

Comment: What exactly is broken? How is it broken? How should it behave? Why do you shout at us (uppercase)? Why don't you try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS you need to use:

```
display:-webkit-flex;   /* for Safari */
display: flex;          /* for others */
```

and add the -webkit- prefix to any other flexbox properties you are using. e.g.:

```
 -webkit-flex-direction: row-reverse;   /* for Safari */
 flex-direction: row-reverse;
```